# Deploy pre-compiled ASP.net Website Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, setup-deployment, web-deployment

I have a precompiled website in the `precompiled` folder inside the `Projects` directory. I want to deploy this website onto IIS7.0

Can anyone guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IIS7ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the .aspx, .aspx.cs and the bin folder into a folder under the IIS server's inetpub directory. If you have any other supporting files such as master templates, web.conf files or XML schema files, you will need to copy these files too.